# How is this electronic sound made

Tags: electronic-music, electronic-drumset

Between 2:59 and 3:25 of the song Charlie Brown by Coldplay [(song link)](https://youtu.be/zTFBJgnNgU4) some sort of vocal electronic sound can be heard. It is not the first time I hear this kind of sound and I was wondering how is it achieved.

Comment: Note: the same sound can be heard at the very beginning of the song too

Comment: Just a synth sound going through something like a phazer. Not sure, but figure it out...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a sample being played faster than originally recorded. There are a couple of videos on Youtube that feature the intro played back at different speeds:

[Coldplay Charlie Brown Intro Slowed Down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Yjo_3k2rpg)

[Coldplay - The Secret of Charlie Brown Intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z30Pl5USqy4)

Beyond that, the sample is washed out with a lush reverb, set with a pretty much 100% wet/effected signal. The sample is also rigorously EQ'd with all low frequencies removed.